# Display QImage with QtGui

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qtgui

I am new to Qt, and I am trying to create a simple GUI Application that displays an image once a button has been clicked on.

I can read the image in a `QImage` object, but is there any simple way to call a Qt function that takes the `QImage` as an input, and displays it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks All, I found how to do it, which is the same as Dave and Sergey:

I am using QT Creator:

In the main GUI window create using the drag drop GUI and create label (e.g. "myLabel")

In the callback of the button (clicked) do the following using the (*ui) pointer to the user interface window:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QImage imageObject;
     imageObject.load(imagePath);
     ui->myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageObject));

     //OR use the other way by setting the Pixmap directly

     QPixmap pixmapObject(imagePath");
     ui->myLabel2->setPixmap(pixmapObject);
}
```

Answer (score 79):

Simple, but complete example showing how to display QImage might look like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QImage myImage;
    myImage.load("test.png");

    QLabel myLabel;
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));

    myLabel.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Drawing an image using a `QLabel` seems like a bit of a kludge to me. With newer versions of Qt you can use a `QGraphicsView` widget. In Qt Creator, drag a `Graphics View` widget onto your UI and name it something (it is named `mainImage` in the code below). In `mainwindow.h`, add something like the following as `private` variables to your `MainWindow` class:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene;
QPixmap image;
```

Then just edit `mainwindow.cpp` and make the constructor something like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    image.load("myimage.png");
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->addPixmap(image);
    scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());

    ui->mainImage->setScene(scene);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about a less kludgy way of doing it myself. Maybe I'm weird, but I think a label should be a label, not a picture.

Comment: This does not seem very convenient for displaying lots of images per second though :(

Comment: @TomášZato Calling `setPixmap` on the returned `QGraphicsPixmapItem` to change the image seems pretty convenient. That method can be found by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 14):

One common way is to add the image to a `QLabel` widget using `QLabel::setPixmap()`, and then display the `QLabel` as you would any other widget. Example:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPixmap pm("your-image.jpg");
  QLabel lbl;
  lbl.setPixmap(pm);
  lbl.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working very fine, I just moved it inside the callback of the button.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, `QPixmap` is used for displaying images and `QImage` for reading them. There are `QPixmap::convertFromImage()` and `QPixmap::fromImage()` functions to convert from `QImage`.

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html): `Qt provides four classes for handling image data: QImage, QPixmap, QBitmap and QPicture. QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and for direct pixel access and manipulation, while QPixmap is designed and optimized for showing images on screen. QBitmap is only a convenience class that inherits QPixmap, ensuring a depth of 1. The isQBitmap() function returns true if a QPixmap object is really a bitmap, otherwise returns false. Finally, the QPicture class is a paint device that records and replays QPainter commands.`