# QGridLayouts within a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qgridlayout

Is it possible to have `QGridLayouts` within another `QGridLayout`? I have been trying to do this using the UI designer, so that I can resize all QGridLayouts uniformly.

This is for an Ultimate-Tic-Tac-Toe game I am creating for fun.

Here, I have nine QGridlayouts. I want to group them together. If I want to expand the boxes, I have to go through each one and expand them. Or I have to copy/paste the first box and make sure they are all aligned again.

[image]

I tried selecting all of them and clicking `Lay Out in a Grid` , but that messes up how they are displayed. Especially the lines that separate the layouts. Am I not doing this correctly?

This just looks weird:

[image]

Comment: Layouts like this typically are best suited to doing with code vs. in the designer.  Perhaps the spirit of [my answer about this battleship game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335025/qt-update-pixmap-grid-layout-with-2d-array-values) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no any problems inserting `QGridLayout` into another `QGridLayout`. Here is a demonstration how it can be done in the designer.
Pay attention that there are no any lines when you open the widget in the Preview: they are visible only for design purposes.
Buttons are added to the layouts just to see how they are places in the Preview.

[image]