# How to represent Gomoku board with QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a graphical interface for the gomoku game and I am trying to find out the best way to represent the board. This is an example of a gomoku board of size 15x15:

[image: gomoku board 15x15]

I'm an absolute beginner with QT and I briefly read some of the documentation, but couldn't figure out the best way to do it. I'm trying to make it look somewhat like the image above (but not the same dimensions).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Generally speaking, the idea of asking a question here is that you show some code (even bad code)...and people guide you toward better.  It's not a free code writing service, but also: if we can't see examples of what you've already tried, it's not clear what kind of answer you would understand.  Note the EDIT button, can you add some of anything you've attempted so people can guide you?  You might also [look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8335025/)  *(Note that if your question is closed, editing to add details will cause a review for reopening.)*

Comment: Thank you for your edit and guidance. I have not yet implemented the GUI and this is why I did not add any code. I checked out your answer and I'm going to try something like that and see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple QGraphicsRectItem classes with different positions http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html