# QImage::load jpg not plotting to view / scene?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

Image is not being plotted to the screen?

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 996, 996);
scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);

QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
view->setScene(scene);
view->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white);
view->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
view->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
view->setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "Colliding Mice"));
view->resize(1000, 1000);
view->show();

QImage img(996, 996, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
img.load("/home/blabla/scene8.jpg", 0);
QPainter painter(&img);
view->render(&painter, view->sceneRect());
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? After setting up the scene and view, you create a QImage and render a jpg to it. You need to show the code that's adding an object to the scene that contains the QImage, or is this all you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using for a basis:  [Display QImage with QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474086/display-qimage-on-qt-gui)

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();

QPixmap image;
image.load("/home/blabla/scene8.jpg", 0);
scene->addPixmap(image);
scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());

QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
view->setScene(scene);
view->setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "My Plot"));
view->resize(1000, 1000);
view->show();
```