# Modify alpha channel transparency of a windowless QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I have a very small Qt application that uses labels to display a jpeg image without first putting it in a window.  (I got a lot of help from [Display QImage with QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474086/display-qimage-with-qtgui))

Now I would like to change the alpha channel of this jpeg to make the image partially transparent.  I have tried the following without any luck

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel label (0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    label.resize(1280,720);
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap("test.jpg"));
    label.setScaledContents(true);

    // This line should set the alpha transparency to 50%
    label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255,255,255,50);");

    label.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It seems like the Style Sheet isn't affecting the label at all.  I have experimented with changing the other rgb values (all 0's for instance) and alternated between the background-color and the color, but the image is always the same.

Update:
Thanks to eyllanesc, the following now works for me:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QPixmap input ("test.jpg");
     QImage image(input.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
     image.fill(Qt::transparent);
     QPainter p(&image);
     p.setOpacity(0.5);
     p.drawPixmap(0,0,input);
     p.end();

     QPixmap output = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

     QLabel label (0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
     label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255,255,255,50);");
     label.resize(1280,720);
     label.setPixmap(output);
     label.setScaledContents(true);
     label.show();

     return app.exec();
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the image background slightly transparent while leaving the rest of the image fully opaque? Or are you trying to make the entire jpg transparent? I don't believe that jpgs support alpha channels so you can't have partially transparent jpg images, but you can make the entire image transparent using either custom rendering or a QGraphicsOpacityEffect graphics effect.

Comment: I need to make the entire image transparent.  My goal would be to have a still picture (jpeg, png, etc) as an overlay for some video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StyleSheet` is working fine, the problem is that the `QPixmap` object is drawn on the background (not the background). If you want `QPixmap` to be transparent you can use one of two methods:

1. First Method:

---

```
QPixmap input("test.jpg");

QImage image(input.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
image.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter p(&image);
p.setOpacity(0.2);
p.drawPixmap(0, 0, input);
p.end();

QPixmap output = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
label.setPixmap(output);
```

2. Second Method:

---

```
QPixmap input("test.jpg");
QPixmap output(input.size());
output.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter p(&output);
p.setOpacity(0.2);
p.drawPixmap(0, 0, input);
p.end();

label.setPixmap(output);
```

Comment: If my answer will help you mark it as correct please.

Comment: "object is drawn on the background (not the background)" that doesn't sound right...