# svg background for QGraphicsView C++

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qgraphicsview

I would like to put an svg image as background to my QGraphicsView without repetition and preserving the ratio. Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It depends on you want to add one `svg` as your Items means that you want it as one Item in your scene, or just you want to set it as the background image. I create an example for you. If you want to set the image as background in one widget it doesn't matter its `normal Qwidget or QGraphicsView` you can use `stylesheet`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024055/6894386 .
this code will add images to QGraphicsView.

Comment: @MarekR The last thing I tried was to just put a setBackgroundBrush(myPath) but my image is split in 4. The top left part of the image ends up in the bottom right, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a background that fits the size of the object I created a class that inherits from QGraphicsScene and I rewrote drawBackground by putting my svg image in it.
myscene.h

```
class myscene : public QGraphicsScene
{
 public:
   myscene();
   ~myscene();

   void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect);
};
```

myscene.cpp

```
myscene::myscene():QGraphicsScene()
{
}

myscene::~myscene()
{
}

void myscene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    painter->drawImage(rect, QImage(":myPathImage.svg"));
}
```

Then in my QGraphicsView I passed it this scene and it works.
myview.h:

```
class myview : public QGraphicsView
{
private :
   myscene* _scene;

public: 
   myview();
   ~myview();

};
```

myview.cpp:

```
myview::myview() : QGraphicsView()
{
  _scene = new myscene();

  this->setScene(_scene);
  this->showMaximized();
}

myview::~myview()
{
   delete _scene;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just edit, is it better ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one Example :

First of all add  `QT += svgwidgets` in your `.pro`.

then add one `graphicsView` in your `UI` File :

[image]

**in mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**in mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsSvgItem>
#include <QSvgRenderer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    QGraphicsSvgItem *item = new QGraphicsSvgItem(":/images/images/diagramTool.svg");

    scene->addItem(item);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**output :**

[image]

**And there is one easy way you can add this stylesheet in your graphics view :**

```
  background-image: url(":/images/images/diagramTool.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border-style:none;
```

This will add `SVG` as your background image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's works but if my QGraphicsView changes size the image does not follow.

Comment: @tyler you should use Layout, look at this doc [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into it.